# Custom login System for Fourm Website

Tags: php, authentication, system, admin

this is my first post on stackoverflow. Anyway, I am working on a and I would like to implement a login system with a couple features. I have spent the last week researching, download, and trying over 20 different login systems and have problems with them, or they are too basic. I currently have a basic login system working now that has register with no email confirm, login, edit account, logout, and a member list. See more here: http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-and-stickies-167/how-to-program-a-basic-but-secure-login-system-using-891201.html 
Here are the things I would like it to include, I just don't know the best way to do it:
- registration with email confirmation
- forum area where members can post stuff
- avatar for each member to upload
- some kind of online chat 
- admin control over user accounts (modifiy/ban users)
- some kind of captcha for register and timeout for login to prevent brute force hacking

That is what I would like to accomplish, my question is how do I implement those into my login system? If anyone can lead me in the right direction on how these fit together that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a pretty loaded first question, so don't anticipate too many complete answers. 

To be perfectly honest, it sounds like you should buy some pre-made forum software like IP.Board or VBulletin which takes care of all that for you. That list you've posted is at least 3 months of solid work for a very experienced web developer, and if you went to a web development agency for a custom solution, it would cost you close to $10,000-15,000 (just to give you an idea of the scope involved).

Comment: Holy crap! lol I guess I didn't realize the magnitude of what I want to do... wow. I will defiantly look into those pre-made softwares and see where that leads me. Thanks for your comment.